# Ruby two if blocks - use a guard clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using [jira-ruby gem](https://github.com/sumoheavy/jira-ruby) to create an jira issue using my app. The ticket on Jira board should be created in one or two board depend on which action was triggered before. For example when new member was added to the repo it should create two tickets in two separate boards (support and security). I've to use `client.Issue.build` twice (this is a gem method) so I need to do something like:

```
      def call
        if SUPPORTBOARD_WEBHOOKS_CLASSES.include?(webhook.action_type_class)
          issue = client.Issue.build
          issue.save({"fields"=>{"summary"=>"example.rb","project"=>{"id"=>"10001"},"issuetype"=>{"id"=>"3"}}})
        end

        if SECURIY_WEBHOOKS_CLASSES.include?(webhook.action_type_class)
          issue = client.Issue.build
          issue.save({"fields"=>{"summary"=>"example.rb","project"=>{"id"=>"10001"},"issuetype"=>{"id"=>"3"}}})
        end
      end
```

But I'm getting an error from rubocop: `use a guard clause`

Comment: I would argue that it is perfectly fine to ignore Rubocop _warning_ when it makes sense. Usually following Rubocop's leads to more code that is easier to read and to maintain. But in this example, IMO your version is better than the version Rubocop prefers because you have two similar if-conditions doing similar stuff in the block. To write both blocks differently would actually make it harder to understand what is going on.

Comment: You pass `issue.save` to `issue.save` on the 1st call – is that a typo? Besides, the parameters for the 1st and 2nd call seem identical. Wouldn't that create two identical tickets on the same board?

Comment: @Stefan it was a typo, updated. The part with `"fields"=>{"summary" ....` are in a separate method, they are not the same (eg. different `issuetype` and `summary` etc) - I put it on purpose as a custom example to not foggy the topic.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
def call
  if SUPPORTBOARD_WEBHOOKS_CLASSES.include?(webhook.action_type_class)
    issue = client.Issue.build
    issue.save(issue.save({"fields"=>{"summary"=>"example.rb","project"=>{"id"=>"10001"},"issuetype"=>{"id"=>"3"}}}))
  end

  return unless SECURIY_WEBHOOKS_CLASSES.include?(webhook.action_type_class)

  issue = client.Issue.build
  issue.save({"fields"=>{"summary"=>"example.rb","project"=>{"id"=>"10001"},"issuetype"=>{"id"=>"3"}}})
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the rubocop rule is trying to prevent large if/else logic at the top of methods. The rule helps limit how much indenting is going on inside of a method.

It looks to me like the block of code inside of both of your 'if' blocks are the same. Assuming SUPPORTBOARD_WEBHOOKS_CLASSES and SECURIY_WEBHOOKS_CLASSES are arrays you can do this:

```
  def call
    if (SUPPORTBOARD_WEBHOOKS_CLASSES | SECURIY_WEBHOOKS_CLASSES).include?(webhook.action_type_class)
      issue = client.Issue.build
      issue.save({"fields"=>{"summary"=>"example.rb","project"=>{"id"=>"10001"},"issuetype"=>{"id"=>"3"}}})
    end
  end
```

Or if you really wanted to use the guard clause rule:

```
  def call
    return unless (SUPPORTBOARD_WEBHOOKS_CLASSES | SECURIY_WEBHOOKS_CLASSES).include?(webhook.action_type_class)
    
    issue = client.Issue.build
    issue.save({"fields"=>{"summary"=>"example.rb","project"=>{"id"=>"10001"},"issuetype"=>{"id"=>"3"}}})
  end
```